# How to bypass authentication for an HTML5 web app on the iPad?

Tags: windows, ipad, html, web-applications

Our enterprise has developed a number of HTML5 web apps that sit on our Windows servers. Our users love them, except every time they switch from one application to another on their iPads, they are then prompted for their network credentials for authentication. Safari Mobile only requires authentication once at the beginning of a session, why do web apps constantly need to be authenticated?

Is there any way at all to sidestep all this constant authentication? It's a real barrier to productivity.

Comment: Are you talking about HTTP basic authentication or some authentication within the apps themselves?

Comment: I am talking about Windows network authentication as the apps are on our intranet web servers. I should also mention that this is for HTML5 web apps that have been pinned to the home page so they run in full screen. When they run in Safari Mobile, I only need to authenticate them at the bginning of the session.